# Xcode Error when compiling app: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid

Tags: xcode, dynamic

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't locate file for: -lzbar
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   file: -lzbar is not an object file (not allowed in a library) Command
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   failed with exit code 1

This error is occurring on a sub project while compiling the main project to run.  This sub project, opened by itself, will build and run tests just fine.

Comment: it is showing some `lzbar` file is unable to locate. Is this file exists?

Comment: yea, didn't know what zbar was... but it was a lib file that was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the zbar lib file was missing.

Comment: My zbar.lib file was physically missing from my file system.  I re-downloaded or otherwise re-found it and put it back in its directory.